# How to create a floating mutlicolumn layout in CSS (Flexbox, float, inline-block)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First let me describe the situation - i want to achive the following layout:

[image]

You see the red aside element is basically just floating to the right, every other element tries to fit the remaining space until it just breaks to the next line.

Currently i'm using a flexbox layout, where main and main#2 have flex: 1 1 70%; and the yellow widgets have flex: 1 1 50%;. Now the tricky part is, i don't want to specify which elements are at the left of the red aside box or not. Basically only aside has a fixed width(although in percentage). All other elements can be of varying sizes and height. So sometimes it might be that main#2 is not so tall, so that widgets might also be positioned side-by-side to the red aside element but belor main#2.

My current approach with flexbox and a container with

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:row-reverse;
flex-wrap:wrap;
```

gives me this:
[image: actual result]

The problem is flexbox does not allow 2 rows left and one row right, i fear there is just no way how to solve this. Floating is not an option because i cannot use overflow:hidden and also floating would not allow me to specify that the element should itself fill up the remaining space or be e.g. 50% if it fits(one of the advantages of flexbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it you need footer to be on the left side of the sidebar when content height is smaller and full width bellow sidebar when content is higher.

I made it by using floats, and flex to stretch widgets. Note that you don't need to use overflow hidden to clear floats.

Here is a [Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqgw6k0t/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <div>
            main
        </div>
        <div>
            main#2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        aside        
    </div>

    <div class="footer clearfix">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <div class="widget">widget</div>
            <div class="widget">widget</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    clear: left;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.footer {
    clear: left;
}
.footer-inner {
    display: flex;
    background: yellow;
}
.widget {
    flex: 1;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: unbelievable, you did it! I really like how you even prepared a test scenario with a slider to demonstrate the behaviour :) For all others, here is also a version without fixed css heights, so it's more like in the real world. http://jsfiddle.net/fqgw6k0t/

Of course the only drawback is that the green items do not automatically wrap, but that is something not really possible, as the browser has to be told, how you want to layout the items below the bottom line

Answer (score 0):

This is an old-school layout - not a bad thing :) - and `display: table` is a pretty straightforward solution.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/wegal/1/edit) - all divs.

[Have a more semantic example!](http://jsbin.com/jarak/1/edit) - obviously you can forgo `div.wrap` and throw in HTML5 semantic elements.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="inner">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="footer-wrap">
        <div class="footer"></div><div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.left,.right {
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    width: 30%;
    background: red;
}
.left {
    width: 70%;
    background: green;
}
.inner {
    height: 50%;
}
.footer-wrap {
    display: table-row;
}
.footer {
    background: yellow;
    height: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: hey, unfortunately this is not what i wanted. The left items do not automatically align themself below the right item. for example if i have a xth left item that does not fit on the left side anymore, it should automatically "break" to the bottom. http://jsbin.com/dicodaqapufi/1/